# Make a field invisible based on Many2one field value(name and not ID) in openerp 6.1

Tags: python, odoo

```
employee_category_m2o':fields.many2one('employee.transition.category','Category')
```

is my field. If user has selected Contract Labour in that `many2one` field then another char field '`grade`' should be made invisible.

Answer (score 1):

For this first you need the external id of the option "Contract Labour" of the many2one.

After you get the external id then it is very simple.
You just need to provide attrs to that "grade" field in xml.

```
<field name="grade" attrs="{'invisible':[('employee_category_m2o','=',%(External id of Contract Labour)d)]}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But that doesn't solve my problem. What I want is something like this                                                                              <xpath expr="//field[@name='grade']" position="attributes">    
    <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible':[('gender','=','female')]}</attribute>
   </xpath> -->

Comment: I just want to use the name values specified in my many2one table and not the ID since IDs will be different but not the names.

Comment: Then there is only way that create selection field instead of many2one.